# Why Throwable::printStackTrace holding lock of PrintStream and cause deadlock of logback

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, logback, deadlock

Found a deadlock situation when using `e.printStackTrace()` and logback in different threads. The thread dumps are given below.

It seems to me, the logback (used in thread `AsyncAppender-Worker-Thread-1`) trying to acquire the lock of `PrintStream`, which is already owned by by `main thread`'s `java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println`. If that's the case, why the `printStackTrace` keep holding the lock of `PrintStream` (as it should release it once the printing is done)?

Thread dump For the `main thread`.

```
"main@1" prio=5 tid=0x1 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks AsyncAppender-Worker-Thread-1@831
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:353)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.put(AsyncAppenderBase.java:139)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.append(AsyncAppenderBase.java:130)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:273)
      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:260)
      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:442)
      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:396)
      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:543)
      at com.side.stdlib.logging.StdOutErrLog$2.print(StdOutErrLog.java:43)
      at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:823)
      - locked <0x1183> (a com.side.stdlib.logging.StdOutErrLog$2)
      at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintStream.println(Throwable.java:749)
      at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:698)
      at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:668)
      at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:644)
      at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:635)
      at com.side.SidekApi.sideAPIExecution(SidekApi.java:175)
```

Thread dump for the thread `AsyncAppender-Worker-Thread-1`

```
"AsyncAppender-Worker-Thread-1@831" daemon prio=5 tid=0xe nid=NA waiting for monitor entry
  java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
     waiting for main@1 to release lock on <0x1183> (a com.side.stdlib.logging.StdOutErrLog$2)
      at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:478)
      at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConsoleTarget$2.write(ConsoleTarget.java:55)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder.doEncode(LayoutWrappingEncoder.java:135)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeOut(OutputStreamAppender.java:194)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:219)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:103)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:88)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
      at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase$Worker.run(AsyncAppenderBase.java:226)
```

It seems the situation is a bit similar with https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6719464, but no answer there.

Comment: Looks to me like both threads are using logback code to print. One possible explanation is the underlying IO is broken for some reason. Another explanation would be a bug in logback

Comment: Looks like you try to print the log to stderr, while redirecting stderr to be logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logback worker thread can't finish, it must be because its blocking queue is full. The worker is waiting to deposit its log entry, and since the thread is WAITING we know it released the lock on the queue, but it still holds the lock on the printstream. The console writing thread is BLOCKED trying to acquire the lock on the printstream, which it needs in order to write to the console, so they are deadlocked.

A minimal fix that avoids code changes could be swapping out the console appender for one that doesn't need to acquire a lock on the printstream.

In any case needing to take the lock on the printstream probably reduces the benefit from logging asynchronously. The long term fix will involve replacing the printlns with calls to a logger (like slf4j).

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Sorry for late reply.. Regarding `The worker is waiting to deposit..., and since the thread is WAITING we know it released the lock on the queue, but it still holds the lock on the printstream. `, if I understand correctly, currently the logback holds the lock of the printStream,  while console wants the printStream.. What I don't understand is why logback worker won't release the lock for printStream? Because of the full blocking queue? Then why the queue is full and nothing got deleted?